# Stack Overflow日本語版をソーシャルメディアで共有してもいい？

Tags: サポート, プライベートベータ

現在Stack Overflow日本語版は**プライベートベータ中**です。

どういう意味ですか？ソーシャルメディア等で情報を共有していい？

Answer (score 5):

**もちろん。** うわさを生むのがいいです。

念のために、下記の点を意識してください：

1. **現在はプライベートベータのため、招待なしでサイトが見れません**　質問や回答へのリンクを共有しても、アカウントのない方々が参照できません。
2. **完成品ではないです**　まだ未翻訳の文書や多少のバグが残っているため、正式オープンまでは改善に努力をしています。問題点があればメタでの投稿や、直接jmaciel@stackoverflow.comにご教示ください。
3. **正式オープンの時期はまだ未定です**　みんな様の支援で思った以上に注目されていますが、バグや翻訳に時間がかかるため、正式オープンの予定は検討中です。早くとも来年の1月になります。

上記に含まれていない質問があったら、メール（jmaciel@stackoverflow.com）で回答できますし、メタで投稿すればここにも回答します。

Comment: 今来たばかりですが、今、ユーザー数どのくらいなのでしょうか

Comment: @shigeya, [ユーザーリストを見れば分かる](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate)が、現在10人ぐらいです（今日招待を送りましたので、今日・明日増えるはずです）。少人数で討議等がやりやすいため、まだ英語のSOで500Rep以上の日本人ユーザーしか誘っていないです。

Comment: おおそうですか。てっきり50人ぐらいはいるのかと思ってました。では、そのつもりで見てみますね

Comment: なるほど。了解しました！拡散協力いたします！

Comment: 自分が他のユーザを招待することはできますか？

Comment: @kawty ベータのログインリンクは数人も使えるため、招待することは可能です。当社側から送ることもできますが、そのリンクを友達と共有した方が早い可能性もあります。