# スタック・オーバーフローについての「よくある質問」の一覧

Tags: サポート, よくある質問

## よくある質問

[「よくある質問」](/q/1484)（FAQ）は、メタ内にある[よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)タグが付けられたQ&Aの集まりです。[Stack Exchange全体のメタ][se-faq] (英語) では、100個以上のよくある質問がユーザーの手で保守されており、公式の[ヘルプ](/help)より詳しい動作仕様や、サイト内の運用ポリシーで重要なものが Q&A の形で保全されています。

日本語版でも、役立つ資料集として育てていきましょう。

### 質問・回答

- [製品やライブラリの公式サイトからこのサイトを訪れた方へ](/q/2111)
- [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](/q/2314)
- [質問や回答に書いたソースコードをきれいに表示したい](/q/2068)
- [回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](/q/1735)
- [コメントの@返信の仕方を教えてください](/q/328)
- [「XY 問題」とは何ですか？](/q/2701)
- [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](/q/2418)
- [スニペット実行とは？](/q/1825)
- [リンク集や関連する質問を設定することはできますか？](/q/1909)
- [質問の回答を受けて別の質問を追加したい時はどうしたら良い？](/q/3345)
- [公開してはいけない情報を質問や回答として投稿してしまいました。どうすれば良いですか？](/q/3004)

### モデレーション

- [知らない間にコメントが削除されている](/q/1977)
- [レビューを変更することはできますか](/q/1898)

### サイトの仕組み

- [一部のタグを非表示にしたり、上手に検索したりする方法](/q/2003)
- [回答がプラス票の多い順に表示されないのはなぜですか？](/q/1915)
- [間違えて作成したアカウントを統合・マージ・リンクする方法はありますか？](/q/2092)
- [チャットルームの作り方は？](/q/1618)
- [Community ユーザーというのは誰ですか？](/q/1418)

### その他

- [サイト内で英語が残っている箇所・日本語がおかしい箇所を見つけたときは？](/q/2160)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー 専門用語の和訳一覧](/q/3502)
- [Stack OverflowのQ&AデータにアクセスできるAPIはありますか？](/q/1621)
- [Stack Exchange Data Explorer の使い方を教えてください](/q/1953)
- [質問・回答・スニペットのマークアップ練習場](/q/331)
- [サイトの和訳で役立つ参考資料まとめ](/q/226)
- [質問-回答-投票の仕方-まとめ](/q/1979)

### 運用ポリシーを話し合う上での参考資料

<sup>ここにはQ&A形式ではない、ブログ記事の和訳なども含めます。[stackoverflow.blog](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.blog)も合わせてご覧ください。</sup>

- [「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](/q/1381)
- [Q&A って大変だな、買い物にでも出かけよう！](/q/1432)
- [いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](/q/1485)
- [英語版SOやStack Exchange全般ではオフトピックな質問や、よしとされない回答を日本語版SOで見たらどうすればいいですか?](/q/292)
- [英語が残っている箇所-プライベートベータでの質問方法-ページの-関連サイト](/q/292)

---

### よくある質問に記事を追加する手順

- まずメタに質問を投稿する: 回答が既に分かっている場合でも、質問本文には質問だけを簡潔に書き、回答は回答として投稿する。
- この目次へのリンクを含める。以下を質問の最後にコピペすればOK:

```
[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)
```

- タグは [よくある質問の案](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e6%a1%88) と [サポート](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%9d%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88) を付ける。よくある質問に加えて問題ない内容になり次第、モデレーターが [よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f) に付け替える。
- 質問を「通報」して、モデレーターに**コミュニティWiki**にしてもらう。コミュニティWikiではない「よくある質問」があったら、見つけ次第コミュニティWikiにする。
- [よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f) タグが追加されたら、質問をこの目次にも追加する。

#### アーカイブ: プライベートベータ中のよくある質問

- [スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6)
- [当サイトを改善するための提案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5)
- [日本語に違和感のある箇所をおしえてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4)
- [英語がまだ残っている箇所をおしえてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3)
- [Stack Overflow日本語版をソーシャルメディアで共有してもいい？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/112)

Comment: この投稿を，何らかの方法で sticky にするようなことは可能でしょうか？ つまり，meta.ja.stackoverflow.com を開いた時に，トップページあるいはそれに近いところから常にこの投稿を発見し，容易にアクセスできるようにリンクをおいておくことはできますか？現在この投稿は「アクティブ」の1ページ目下の方に載っていたので発見できましたが，これが2ページ目以降に行ってしまうと，せっかくの一覧記事が埋もれてしまいそうに思います．

Comment: @Yosh ご指摘ありがとうございます。メタのトップページのサイドバーに、「よくある質問」一覧を表示するようにjmacさんに設定してもらいました。また、[meta-tag:注目]タグもつけました (こちらは一定日数が過ぎたら外すかも)。

Comment: @ ento ずいぶん見つけやすくなったと思います，ありがとうございます！

Comment: [質問・回答・投票の仕方まとめ](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1979/8000)を取り込みたい気もしますが、あの形のまま整備したほうがわかりやすいですかねえ・・・

Answer (score 2):

## 英語の資料

### 質問を書く準備

- [デバッグの技法](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
- [今までに何を試してみましたか？](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)
- [完全無欠な質問を書く](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

  - [meta.so: 質問を書く時のチェックリスト](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

### 運用に関する議論

- [meta.programmers.se: ディスカッションはなぜよくないか](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)
- [meta.startups.se: タグWikiにはWikipediaの記事をコピペするのがよいのか](https://startups.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/3738)

### サイトの仕様

- [meta.physics.se: 通報ガイドライン](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5768/should-we-still-be-flagging-answers)
- [meta.se: 投稿はいつ削除されるか](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
- [meta.se: コメント全般](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

### Stack Exchangeの設計思想

- [コミュニティは得てして自己崩壊する](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html)
- [Stack Overflowとゲーミフィケーション](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/)