# 質問文に追加質問や回答を追記しないガイドラインはありますか

Tags: サポート

スタックオーバーフローに慣れていないユーザが、質問文を大幅に書き換えることで質問と回答の内容が乖離するケースや質問と回答が混同されるケースが散見されます。

下記の例に遭遇した時に誘導できるヘルプページやメタ質問があれば、コメント返しで文言を考えずに済んでありがたいです。
このような場合の誘導に適切なページはあるでしょうか？

- [回答で得た新たな追加質問を質問文に埋め込む](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67575/9820)

  - 質問も回答も長くなるので、新しい質問を提示していただく方がQAの価値が高くなります。
- [完全に質問文を上書きする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67168/9820)

  - 私の回答は質問にかすりもしない珍妙な回答になってしまっています。
    ※『解決済み』にしていただいた後に質問文を書き換えても通知が来ないので、今日改変に気付きました。
- コメントで追加質問をする

  - 程度の問題はありますが、回答欄のコメントに長いコードを貼り付けて質問とは別の疑問を投げかけるなど、新たな質問を作成した方が話が早そうな例をしばしば見かけます。
    ヘルプページの[どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)や[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)は追加質問に対する直接的な言及はないように思います。
- 質問の末尾に回答を追記する

  - 質問と回答を分離しないとスタックオーバーフローのリンクや回答済みなどの機能を生かせません。
- 解決済みの質問を削除する

  - だいぶ前に「解決済みのため質問を削除します」と自身の質問を削除する例を見かけました。
    これはもうガイドラインから逸脱しているかもしれませんが…。

Comment: 「解決済みの質問を削除」はプラス票のある回答があれば実行できないので、"日頃から投票は大切" という話にも繋がりますね。 / とはいえ誰かが気づく前に削除されてしまうケースも有るかと思うので、不必要な質問の削除と思われる場合には「削除の取り消し」に票を入れたりモデレーターに通報等で知らせてもらう形でよいかと思います。

Comment: ガイドラインがあるか、とは離れてしまうのでコメントにしますが、完全に質問文が上書きされてしまった場合、ロールバック編集を行った後にコメントで別の質問にして欲しい旨をお願いする方法があります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私の知る限り、現状すべてがまとまった形のページは無いです。

ヘルプはモデレーターしか編集できないので、コミュニティで柔軟に編集できる案内先としてはメタに FAQ を用意するのが便利です。

「関連した質問をするにはどうすれば良いですか？　質問の内容が大幅に変わった場合どうすれば良いですか？」みたいな FAQ を用意して、今回の内容それぞれに対応するような回答をコミュニティ wiki としてまとめていく形です。

FAQ のテンプレートが [メタ内FAQ記事の一覧](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1484/19110) にあるのでここから書き始めると便利です。

Comment: この質問をまとめた[FAQ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345/9820)を作成しました。まとまったページがない(はずの)現状とFAQについてお教えいただいたので @nekketsuuu さんの回答で解決済みとさせていただきました。

Answer (score 5):

「追加質問」や「大幅な書き換え」に対してヘルプに誘導するとして、一番シンプルなのは
ヘルプセンターの [誰かが回答してくれたら...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) に項目を追記するのが良いかなと思います。

---

**追記案**

- 質問はいつでも "編集" することができますが、些細な間違いや質問の内容を明確にする目的で使用してください。既に回答が付いた後に質問項目を増やしたり、**元の質問の意図を大幅に書き換えるような編集はしないでください**。
  回答やコメントでのやり取りを踏まえて新たな疑問が出てきた場合には、**新しい質問** として投稿してください。